# How to make a dynamic mapview in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm making an application that has a map and I want the location of the map to change every time the coordinates are different,
I have tried using `ids` to change the value of `lat` and `lon` but it doesn't work, someone help me please

```py
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

kv = '''


Maap:
    elevation: 0
    padding: '0dp'
    size_hint: .95, .83
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    radius: [3]
    MapView:
        id: mapp
        zoom: 5
        lat: 
        lon: 
    Button:
        text: 'Change'
        on_press: root.change()
'''
class Maap(MDCard):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def change(self):
        self.ids.mapp.lat = 13.5435
        self.ids.mapp.lon = -89.5445


class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

App().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding 2 text fields in which 1 had the latitude and 2 the longitude then save the data in 2 variables and then use their values ​​in another function.